# Promise.all convert result with parameter from nested loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise.all

The following loop to call an async function, here a smart contract interaction using web3. I want to get the balance of an array of token by calling balanceOf() and convert it subsequently with the attached usdrate. For parallel processing I am using Promise.all. Obviously, the function below Promise.all() with access [I % currency.length] does not work, since sorted result is not guaranteed.

My question is, how can I multiply the amounts with the correct usdrates attached to the tokens and still use Promise.all?

```js
currencies = [{
    contract: token1,
    usdrate: 0.5
  },
  {
    contract: token2,
    usdrate: 1.0
  },
  {
    contract: token3,
    usdrate: 1.05
  },
  {
    contract: token4,
    usdrate: 1.10
  },
  {
    contract: token5,
    usdrate: 1.40
  },
  {
    contract: token6,
    usdrate: 1.0
  },
  {
    contract: token7,
    usdrate: 1.0
  }
];
}

async function getUsdWealthAsync(addresses) {
  var totalWealth = 0;
  var amountPromises = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < currencies.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
      amountPromises.push(currencies[j].contract.methods.balanceOf(addresses[i]).call());
    }
  }
  await Promise.all(amountPromises).then(function(amounts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++) {
      amounts[i] = Number.parseInt(amounts[i]);
      totalWealth += (amounts[i] / 100) * currencies[i % currencies.length].usdrate;
    }
  })
  return totalWealth;
}
```

Comment: how many currencies and adresses do you have?
because if you have 10 currencies and 10 adresses, would it not fire 100 request parallel? not a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have other great answers.

Another way could be that, you can attach the USD rate along with the result from the `balanceOf` in the promise itself, And then while resolving the promises, you can access the USD rate directly.

Maybe something like this:

```js
async function getUsdWealthAsync(addresses) {
  var totalWealth = 0;
  var amountPromises = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < currencies.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
      const { usdrate, contract } = currencies[j];
      amountPromises.push(
        contract.methods.balanceOf(addresses[i]).call()
          .then((amount) => ({ amount, usdrate }))
      );
    }
  }

  const amounts = await Promise.all(amountPromises);

  for (var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++) {
    const { amount, usdrate } = amounts[i];
    amount = Number.parseInt(amount);
    totalWealth += (amount / 100) * usdrate;
  }

  return totalWealth;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Raghav Garg. Exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 2):

`async` functions always return a `Promise`, you can define an async function that receives an address and a currency and returns a `Promise` that has the calculation done already, so you don't have index troubles. Something like

```js
async function getAmount(currency, address) {
   const amount = await currency.contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call();
   return amount * currency.usdrate;
}


async function getUsdWealthAsync(addresses) {
  const amountPromises = [];
  for (const currency of currencies) {
    for (const address of addresses) {
      amountPromises.push(getAmount(currency,address)/*Remember, calling this funciton returns a Promise*/);
    }
  }
  const realAmounts = await Promise.all(amountPromises)
  return realAmounts.reduce((total,current) => total+current, 0);
}
```

Where the last line with the `reduce` call is supposed to sum all the amounts you have

Comment: Thanks @Ron B. That too, works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a nested `Promise.all()` to bundle all of the asynchronous calls for a particular currency under a single Promise? By doing this, you also retain the index alignment for processing the response.

````js
async function getUsdWealthAsync(addresses) {
    let totalWealth = 0;
    let amountPromises = [];

    // For each of the currencies...
    for (var j = 0; j < currencies.length; j++) {
        // Create a set that will hold balance promises for this currency.
        const balancePromisesForCurrency = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
            // Create those promises and add them to the set.
            balancePromisesForCurrency.push(
                currencies[j].contract.methods.balanceOf(addresses[i]).call()
            );
        }
        // Create a new promise that resolves to the list of balance results, ​
        // index-aligned to the addresses, for this currency. Add that Promise
        // to the set of per-currency Promises, index-aligned to the currencies
        // array.
        amountPromises.push(Promise.all(balancePromisesForCurrency));
    }

    // Create a new cumulative promise from the `amountPromises` array.
    await Promise.all(amountPromises).then(function (amountsForCurrency) {
        // For each of the balance lists received...
        amountsForCurrency.forEach((amounts, amountsIndex) => {
            // Get the corresponding currency.
            const currency = currencies[amountIndex];

            // Total up the balances scaled by the currency's USD rate.
            amounts.forEach((amount, idx) => {
                totalWealth += (+amount / 100) * currency.usdrate;
            });
        });
    })

    return totalWealth;
}```
````